# How send mms with attach in Android 4.0+

Tags: android, attachment, mms

How send mms with attach in Android 4.0+? I try like:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.setType("image/png");
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
                Uri.parse(outputFile.toURL().toString()));
        startActivity(sendIntent);
```

It is work good in htc and samsung, but it is do not work in Nexus 5 (hangouts). I try like:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.putExtra("address", phonesBuilder2.toString());
        sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", editTextTPMessage.getText());
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(makePicture()));
```

But file is not attach. I try very much ways, but all ways have problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.putExtra("sms_body", "Hi how are you"); //Version dependent
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hi how are you"); //Version dependent
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File("/sdcard/file.gif")));
intent.setType("image/gif"); 
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Send"));
```

Comment: What version of Andriod, Hangouts, and Play Services are you using?

For some versions of Hangouts, I have to use intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hi how are you"); instead of sms_body

Comment: Also, why didn't you set the file type in your second example?